# Dividing each row in a dataframe by a vector in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, vector, feature-scaling

I am feature scaling my data before logistic regression.

Everything works perfect until I attempt to divide the columns by the max_min vector. It seems to have worked in each column but not the age column, but I cant seem to find why.

I have previously split the data for testing and training and below I am attempting to scale the X_train data.

```
# Working out the min value for each column and subtracting this from each row in the data
X_train_min = np.array(X_train0.min())
X_train0.sub(X_train_min.squeeze(), axis=1)
```

From the code above I obtain a table where each value has had the minimum value of its column subtracted, which is correct.
Output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjOvR.png)

```
# Working out the max value for each column and the difference between the max and min values
X_train_max = np.array(X_train0.max())
max_min = np.array(X_train0.max()) - np.array(X_train0.min())
print(max_min)
```

Output:

```
[   56     1     3     2     4     3 18174    56     7]
```

Here is where I face a problem:

```
# Dividing each row in the data by the difference between the max and min values of its column
X_train0.div(max_min, axis=1)
```

I have obtained a table where each value has been divided by the vector, apart from the first column 'Age' where the numbers do not correspond to the division.
Output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ2om.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing by `max - min` when `min` is already subtracted. All you need is just to divide by the new max:

```
max_min = np.array(X_train0.max())
```

Comment: The formula I found for feature scaling is (x-min)/(max-min)

Comment: @RebeccaStephens it is true only if you take both max and min before applying the formula. From your code, it looks like you calculate max after subtracting min